# Can I close an input?

Tags: digital-in

I wan't to build a diversity controller similar to [this](https://github.com/sheaivey/rx5808-pro-diversity) one.

> A diversity controller is basically a circuit which detects the strongest RSSI Signal of multiple receivers and provides the data signal of that (the strongest) receiver.

As a receiver I use boscam [RX5808](https://www.foxtechfpv.com/product/5.8G%20modules/rx5808/RX5808-Spec-V1.pdf) receivers.

This receiver can be switchen between 8 channals through a 3 bit output interface. The CH1-3 outputs are active high 5V which got to be pulled to ground.

**Is it possible to put these receiver-outputs on an arduino digital inputs, to either put them on ground or not?**

How exactly do I implement this in software?

Comment: According to the document you linked to, the channel select pins look like internally pulled-up **inputs**, not outputs.

Answer (score 2):

When you output HIGH you connect the pin to +5V. When you output LOW you connect the pin to ground.  It's called a *push-pull* interface, and looks like this:

[image]

When it's set HIGH the p-FET is turned on and the n-FET is turned off. That connects the output direct to VDD. When it's set LOW the p-FET is turned off and the n-FET is turned off. That connects the output direct to GND.

They are just like switches, as depicted to the right. Only one is closed at a time - when HIGH the upper switch is closed, when LOW the lower switch is closed.

So you just connect the output pins of the Arduino direct to the input pins of your device and write either HIGH or LOW to them to set the 5V or GND connections you need.

Comment: So basically, If i set the arduino I/O on HIGH, it's +5v vs +5v which get's 0v, and if I set the I/O to LOW it's +5v vs GND which get's +5V, right?

Comment: .... pardon .... ?